# Очистка терминала во время работы приложения Java

Tags: java, консоль

Изучаю Java и решил написать мелкое приложение которое будет вести учет моих затрат.
Решил начать с обычного консольного приложения.
Оно очень простое sout выводит в терминал меню которое выглядит вот так:
[image: Скрин терминала с моим меню]

И я хочу сделать так что когда я выбираю тот или иной пункт, вводя цифру пункта, предыдущее меню (то что на скрине) исчезает, и уже появляется новое меню или какой либо функционал.
Например ввел я цифру 5, появилось сообщение "Всего хорошего" а меню исчезло
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]